# Connection Failure while calling a REST API in Xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, android, rest, xamarin

While calling a REST API from PCL, The application gets crashed. 
ERRORS
1. Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused).
2. Skipped 1367 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Here is my code.

```
using (client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {                     

                    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://<my server ip>/Service//DataService.svc/?getVehicleInfo?vehicleId="+ id);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        JSONModel jsonVehicle = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONModel>(content);

                        vehicle = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VehicleModel>(jsonVehicle.Result);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
                }

                return vehicle;
            }
```

I am getting this error at GetAsync().
Internet service is enabled in AndroidManifest.xml.
It has been an obstacle in proceeding further. Need help to resolve it.

Comment: Take a look at the double slash here: Service//DataService.svc it may be the problem . Replace with /

Comment: @WPMed Thanks for finding out the fault. Also I had to add Service Certificate Validation in MainActivity to get it done. Now its working as expected.

Comment: I added that as an aswer so you can accept it if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the double slash here: Service//DataService.svc . It may be the problem. Replace with /

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Xamarin, I had a very similar problem with the 6th version of xamarin but with the 7th the problem disappears